# XML-RPC How to convert C# string to java.lang.String

Tags: c#, string, xml-rpc, java.lang.class, java

I'm trying to send data from Visual Studio 2017 C# Application to a rmeote service using XML-RPC as you can see in the following code:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("https://www.mensajerianegocios.movistar.es/SrvConexion")]
public interface ISendSMS : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("MensajeriaNegocios.enviarSMS")]
    string enviarSMS(string usuario, string password, string phone, string text, string rte);
}
ISendSMS proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ISendSMS>();
string result = proxy.enviarSMS(login, password, phone, text, rte);
```

but I get the following error message:
Server returned a fault exception: [0] No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String

How can I convert c# string to java.lang.String? What library I need to import, use, ...?

Kind regards

Comment: Error message says that there is no method with given name that accepts 5 strings as arguments.

Comment: How do you declare this on the Java side? Do you have any documentation about the API?
XML-RPC is a transport protocol that should handle strings in a language-independent format so that you can send it from any language to any other language.

Comment: Method "enviarSMS" is not under my control. It is a method from Movistar API. You can find the documentation PDF at [link](https://www.mensajerianegocios.movistar.es/Manual_Mensajeria_Negocios_API.pdf) at page #20